# the_content() seems to block my ACF-code

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields, the-content

I have this simple code, but can't get the_content and the ACF-code to work together.

If I include the_content() it blocks out the ACF-code, but if I remove the_content() the ACF-code works fine. I suspect there's a very simple solution to this.

I've simplified and removed unnecessary elements from the code below:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php
    if( have_rows('boxes') ): ?>
        <p>This is only shown when the_content() is removed.</p>
    <?php
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: If you use `<?php the_content(); ?>` below of ACF code, then do you see the text "This is only shown when the_content() is removed"?

Comment: Tried that now. Yes, when putting it below the ACF-code I can see both the test-paragraph "This is only shown (…)" and the content.

Apparently it doesn't work when the content is put before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for information, this is a bug in WP and autop. You can view the ticket [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2691) and it does not look like it will be fixed any time soon. The work around is to start your multiline comment with `<!--` and end it with `<!-- -->`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $acf = false;
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        if( have_rows('boxes') ) $acf = true;

        the_content();

        if( $acf == true ):
            echo '<p>This is only shown when the_content() is removed.</p>';
        else :
            // no rows found
        endif;


    endwhile;
?>
```

This is not a perfect solution but a quick workaround.

Comment: It doesn't work – nothing gets displayed. Also, if I put a test-paragraph before the `if( have_rows('boxes') ) $acf = true;` it gets displayed, but if I place it after it doesn't. It seems like anything after `the_content();` and/or your if-line get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out what it was. Actually I think this might be caused by a bug in Wordpress (or perhaps one of the add-ons I'm using).

In the content editor I had blocked out some of the code with "". For some reasonthe closing markup "-->" didn't get registered, so in the code anything after `the_content();` got blocked out.